# How can I add Logger into my jenkinsfile for logging messages

Tags: logging, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkinsfile for my pipeline. How can I configure Logger for logging info, debug or severe messages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pasting here because Googling for "Jenkins how to write to stdout" landed me here.  I wanted to do something similar and wasnt finding much so I posted a similar question and eventually found my own answer.

[Jenkins write a message to Jenkins process's standard out via groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480982/jenkins-write-a-message-to-jenkins-processs-standard-out-via-groovy)