# Jenkins write a message to Jenkins process's standard out via groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Accroding to Jenkins docs:

[When running jenkins.war manually with java -jar jenkins.war, all logging information by default is output to standard out. Many Jenkins native packages modify this behavior to ensure logging information is output in a more conventional location for the platform.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#:%7E:text=Log%20files%20should%20be%20at,jenkins%2Dci.)

We are running Jenkins as a container and I was curious to know if there was some groovy I could write in the Groovy Script Console to print a message that would end up in the standard out logs?

Answer (score 0):

After reading that link a little more, I saw:

> Jenkins uses java.util.logging for logging. The java.util.logging
> system by default sends every log above INFO to stdout.

So after some trial and error in the script console, I finally got:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("InfoLogging");
LOGGER.info("This will print in stdout");
```